# Keycloak 19 Not loading client url like "http://localhost:9090/" --> Index.jsp file 404 (ON ROOT Dir of Tomcat)

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, grails, keycloak

I am facing one issue with Keycloak Security. I have developed one Grails application and Integrated Keycloak for Authentication. I am facing one problem when I deployed the war file as ROOT dir of Tomcat like ROOT.war. It should open when I enter the URL "HTTP://localhost:9090/" in the browser.

Configuration did as below:
Keycloak admin URL: HTTP://localhost:8080/
[image]

When I entered in browser like HTTP://localhost:9090/
It is throwing 404 and showing a blank white page in Browser. But when I entered HTTP://localhost:9090/web --> It is loading the page. I have already set index.gsp in root directory. but it is not loading.

Note: If I remove the keycloak dependency and load the application then It is working fine.

Please help if anyone has fixed this type of issue.

Thanks,
Hardik

Answer (score 0):

After searching couple solutions found the fixes for this issue. If anyone facing same as above issue with keylcoak or spring security you can use below code at tomcat level.

1. Add below code into your Contact.xml file. (Tomcat->Conf->Contact.xml)

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />
```

2. Add rewrite.config file in your WEB-INF folder. Add below code in this config file.

> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
> RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /web/index

This way you can redirect the URL like http://localhost:9090 to HTTP://localhost:9090/web/index

Thanks